# game programming

Tags: game-engine

probably this question have been asked a million times i use c++ but i want to go into game programming,which good game engine uses c++ for scripting thank you

Comment: You might have better luck here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, C++ is not a "scripting" language...

But to answer your question, I personally have used Haafs Game Engine for rich 2D games.

http://hge.relishgames.com/

If you want a real life example that a friend of mine and his buddies wrote using this check out this site.

http://www.smileysmazehunt.com/SmileysMazeHunt.aspx

Its impressive and a load of fun!

Comment: i knw c++ is not a scripting language but i just didnt want the question to seem like i was asking for the language to create a game engine thanks though